# Remove the reference section of documents

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have written a long macro to cleanup multiple word documents in a directory. A part of this macro is to find the paragraph which contains the word "references", "acknowledgements", "note" or "notes", irrespective of their case, and remove the rest of the document.

However, I receive the compile error: method or data member not found for `.End` in `objDoc.Range(objRange.End, objDoc.Range.End)`. I've tried `.Endof` as well, but received the same error.

Any help would be appreciated.

```vb
            ' Remove references section
            ' Find the line which only contains the word "references", "acknowledgments", "note", or "notes"
            Dim objRange As Range
            Set objRange = objDoc.Content
            With objRange.Find
                .ClearFormatting
                .Text = "^13(?i)(references|acknowledgments|notes?)(^13|$)"
                .MatchWildcards = True
                .Execute
                If .Found Then
                    Dim refLine As String
                    refLine = Split(.Parent.Text, "^13")(UBound(Split(.Parent.Text, "^13")) - 1)
                    If Len(refLine) = Len(.Text) Then ' check if the line contains only the word "references", "acknowledgments", "note", or "notes"
                        ' Remove all text from the line containing the word to the end of the document
                        objDoc.Range(.End).Collapse wdCollapseEnd ' Move the cursor to the end of the search range
                        Dim objDeleteRange As Range
                        Set objDeleteRange = objDoc.Range(objRange.End, objDoc.Range.End)
                        objDeleteRange.Delete
                    End If
                End If
            End With
```

Comment: Do you really mean objDoc.Range(objRange.End, objDoc.Range.End) or should that be **objDoc.Range(objRange.start**, objDoc.Range.End)

Comment: Do you know that you can get a copy of a range using the .Duplicate method?

Comment: @freeflow I'm trying to delete all the text after the paragraph in which the only word is "references", or the other words. That's why I have both objRange and objDoc. But I'm new to VBA, so maybe that's not the right way.

Comment: Your first task would be to go into word itself and develop the wildcard search parameters that will find the line(s) you need.  You will find the wildcard searches a bit limited compared to regular regex so your current attempt at finding a line using an Or argument is unlikely to work.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'll do that. But the error I'm receiving is for ".End". Is it related?

Comment: No.  'ObjDoc.Range(.End).Collapse wdCollapseEnd ' is an error because the .End refers to objRange.Find.  If you look in the object browser you will see that find doesn't have an end method.  That said, all of the code in the 'If .Found' block will have to change once you understand how wildcard searches work in Word.  If you haven't already done so, please install the free and fantastic Rubberduck adding for VBA and take a look at the code inspections it produces.